# Can Eclipse run with Z Garbage Collector?

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to change from -XX:+UseG1GC to -XX:+UseZGC in eclipse.ini

```
-vm
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseZGC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

When I tried to run terminal in eclipse to show default GC in used, I found that the eclipse still using -XX:UseG1GC mode instead. Can someone help on this issue?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\eclipse\workspace\testProgram>java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2 -XX:G1ConcRefinementThreads=8 -XX:GCDrainStackTargetSize=64 -XX:InitialHeapSize=263203904 -XX:MarkStackSize=4194
304 -XX:MaxHeapSize=4211262464 -XX:MinHeapSize=6815736 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=251658240 -XX:+Segmented
CodeCache -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation
openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Do you want to use ZGC for Eclipse itself or for Java programs started from within Eclipse? With eclipse.ini you configure Eclipse itself, but not any other programs

Comment: Both eclipse & program if possible.

Comment: So for Eclipse you have added the config, and for programs you either have to specify the parameters in the run configurations or if you execute them in the terminal, add the parameters in the command in the terminal.

Comment: For program, thx for for your advice.
As For eclipse, yes I added the config. But I'm not sure is this the correct way to check the GC in used by eclipse itself~ .  any other way to know is eclipse running in ZGC mode?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not using Eclipse anymore, but AFAIK there is a menu point somewhere under Help or About or similar, where you can check which parameters were actually used for running Eclipse.

Comment: thks. I found a way which I can monitor eclipse's GC in Java Mission Control (JMC). It did works & displayed correctly after changed to ZGC in eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eclipse.ini settings are just used for Eclipse itself, they don't change anything else. To see what Eclipse is using open the "Help > About" dialog ("Eclipse > About" on macOS), click the "Installation Details" button and look at the "Configuration Tab".

For Java programs you run from within Eclipse using the 'Run' command the 'Run Configuration' sets what is used. See the 'VM Arguments' section of the 'Arguments' tab.

You can set default VM arguments for a JRE/JDK in the 'Java > Installed JREs' page of the Preferences.

None of the Eclipse settings changes the options for a 'java' command you run from a terminal.

Comment: I double checked from  Help>About>Installation Detail>Configuration tab. It did contain -XX:UseZGC which I modified before. As for program, will try on that. But I still saw some forum guys try on this run eclipse in ZGC mode. Anyway, thx for reply..

Comment: thks. I found a way which I can monitor eclipse's GC in Java Mission Control (JMC). It did works & displayed correctly after changed to ZGC in eclipse.ini